# Quoting and escaping for mix cmd aliases

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I can, in principle, run any shell commands as mix tasks by defining `aliases` in `mix.exs` that start with `cmd`. But I am struggling with white spaces, quoting, and backslash escaping. Here is some non-working examples:

```
defp aliases do
  f1: ["cmd echo \"two  spaces  between\""],
  f2: ["cmd echo 'two  spaces  between'"],
  f3: ["cmd echo two\ \ spaces\ \ between"],
  f4: ["cmd echo two\\ \\ spaces\\ \\ between"],
end
```

They all just produce string `"two spaces between"`, not what I expected or aimed for, `"two  spaces  between"`:

```
$ for t in f1 f2 f3 f4; do mix $t; done
two spaces between
two spaces between
two spaces between
two spaces between
```

So how can I pass quoted strings to shell commands? And more generally, how is the alias `cmd` target processed before it is run by shell or is it executed directly? What's the logic of removing single and double quotes and backslashes from the command string?

**Update:** More failing cases:

```
  q1: ["cmd echo \"one  two  three\""],         # "one two three"
  q3: ["cmd echo \\\"one  two  three\\\""],     # "one two three"
  q5: ["cmd echo \\\\\"one  two  three\\\\\""], # "one" (!!!)

  f5: [
    """
    cmd echo 'two  spaces  between'
    """
      ],
```

Obviously, I would prefer being able to pass both kinds of quotes for the intended effect but there seems to be some undocumented, and in this context overaggressive and unnecessary sanitation of input string in operation.

I am running this with *Elixir 1.11.1*.

Comment: There are quotes eaten by the shell itself, I believe. Somewhat alongside `[~S|cmd echo \\"two  spaces  between\\"|]` should do.

Comment: Before posting the original question, I already tried with increasing number of backslashes, and always failing. Yours is equivalent with `["cmd echo \\\\\"two  spaces  between\\\\\""]`, right? And with these 5 consequent backslashes I get only "one" printed. Which is even more weird.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is applicable to your situation, but when you define the tasks in local functions it seems to work better:

```
  defp aliases do
    [
      f1: &f1/1,
      f2: &f2/1
    ]
  end

  defp f1(_) do
    Mix.shell().cmd("echo 'two  spaces  between'")
  end

  # or if you just want to display some text
  defp f2(_) do
    Mix.shell().info("two  spaces  between")
  end
```

Output:

```
$for t in f1 f2; do mix $t; done
two  spaces  between
two  spaces  between
```

Comment: This is practical solution, it allows running any shell command. Though understanding what is going on with the attempts to pass shell command via `cmd` prefixed string is still a great mystery.

Answer (score 1):

### Mystery Solved

What is going on? It is about *how the task arguments are parsed*. And *the solution is to quote **the whole shell command** after `cmd` to pass it to the shell without unintended transmogrifications*.

The listed aliases `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4` with non-intended effects

```
defp aliases do                                # BAD!!
  f1: ["cmd echo \"two  spaces  between\""],
  f2: ["cmd echo 'two  spaces  between'"],
  f3: ["cmd echo two\ \ spaces\ \ between"],
  f4: ["cmd echo two\\ \\ spaces\\ \\ between"]
end
```

are *equivalent to running from shell*

```
$ mix cmd echo "two  spaces  between"           # BAD!!!
$ mix cmd echo 'two  spaces  between'
$ mix cmd echo two  spaces  between
$ mix cmd echo two\ \ spaces\ \ between
```

They all output `two spaces between`.

Running

```
$ mix cmd "echo \"two  spaces  between\""       # GOOD!!!
$ mix cmd "echo 'two  spaces  between'"
$ mix cmd "echo two \\ spaces \\ between"
```

gives the intended output `one  two  three`.

So, the answer is that **the shell commands should be quoted in their entirety** like this:

```
defp aliases do                                 # GOOD!!!
  ok1: ["cmd \"echo \\\"two  spaces  between\\\"\""],
  ok2: ["cmd \"echo 'two  spaces  between'\""],
  ok3: ["cmd \"echo two\\ \\ spaces\\ \\ between\""],
end
```

or equivalently (using the `~S` sigil of Aleksei to simplify the quoting):

```
defp aliases() do                               # GOOD!!!
  ok1: [~S|cmd "echo \"two  spaces  between\""|],
  ok2: [~S|cmd "echo 'two  spaces  between'"|],
  ok3: [~S|cmd "echo two\ \ spaces\ \ between"|],
end
```

Then everything works like fancied:

```
$ for t in ok1 ok2 ok3; do mix $t; done
two  spaces  between
two  spaces  between
two  spaces  between
```

### Peeking Behind The Curtain

Looking at elixir source code, file `lib/mix/lib/mix/tasks/cmd.ex` module `Mix.Tasks.Cmd` function `run/1` you can see how the command is passed to shell. It basically comes to this:

```
Mix.shell().cmd(Enum.join(args, " ")
```

where `args` are the shell command arguments after `mix cmd`.

So command `mix cmd echo 'two  spaces'` or alias target `["cmd echo 'two  spaces']` results to calling Mix.Tasks.Cmd.run(["echo", "two  spaces"]) and running

```
Mix.shell().cmd("echo two  spaces")
```

where of course shell does not care how many spaces you have between the words. The working `mix cmd "echo 'two  spaces'"` or alias target `["cmd \"echo 'two  spaces'\""]` results to calling `Mix.Tasks.Cmd.run(["echo 'two  spaces'])` and is put together as

```
Mix.shell().cmd("echo 'two  spaces'")
```

giving the intended effect.

### More Useful Example

The solution to the actual problem I was struggling to accomplish:

```
defp aliases() do
  "check-formatted": [~S/cmd "bash -c 'mix format --check-formatted $(git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD | egrep \"[.]exs?$\")'"/],
  # ...
end
```

(on my machine this requires running through bash to produce a list of file names for `mix format` instead of one huge string of file names).

This gets ugly really quick, so for more complicated scenarios @zwippie's solution of using Elixir functions to define aliases and therein using `Mix.shell().cmd()` to run the steps that need to be accomplished by running external programs is really the superior way to go.

Comment: I wonʼt remove my answer since jours refers to it. +1

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin The `~S` sigil really simplifies quoting... I (a newbie elixirist) will remember it! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Quotes are eaten by the shell itself, and I was always only good at guessing here :)

Apparently, this would work:

```rb
foo: [~S|cmd echo \\\"two\\ \\ spaces\\ \\ between\\\"|]

mix foo
#⇒ "two  spaces  between"
```

Comment: wasn't the idea to have two spaces between the words in the final?

Comment: @Daniel gosh, thank you, updated an answer; I have copy-pasted somewhat wrong.

Comment: See my answer for explanation what is happening (and where the quotes get eaten).